# Add a relationship to logged in user, not content author, on content view?

Tags: 7, views

I want to filter my content view by a field on the logged in user (the content type has that same field). I could implement `hook_query_alter` and add add a where condition with the field from `$global user`, but is there a way to do this out of the box though the UI?

Comment: `I want to filter my content view by a field on the logged in user` ??? Not sure if I understand this correctly. So the logged in user has field x, which containts the word `hello` and you want to the filter the view by the word `hello`?

Comment: @NoSssweat Edited question.

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: The general problem is getting to fields attached to User (specifically the logged-in user) from a content view. Does this make sense?

In my specific case, I have a view that shows pieces of content of a certain content type. On that content type there is a certain field. That same field is also attached to Users. I want to filter the view to only those content pieces that have the same setting as the current user.

Comment: ok I get it now. humm yea I don't think there is a way with just the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this via UI. At least not if the User field may contain multiple values.

In the example below `'field_test' is a List(text)` field w/ select widget (unlimited values allowed for user account). When the same field is added to Content type - I set it to allow for single values.

The code will take in consideration multiple values from User field and add **`WHERE`**  clause to the View that shows all nodes of a Content type.

**`WHERE`** clause filters out all nodes that have `'field_test'` set to anything other than what currently logged in user has set in `'field_test'` on their own account.

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_query_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // 'test_related_field' -> view's machine_name
  if ($view->name == 'test_related_field') {
    global $user;
    $user = user_load($user->uid);

    // 'field_test' -> field that is shared between user accounts ans content type
    $user_field = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_test');
    if($user_field) {
        $query->ensure_table("field_data_field_test");
        // create query that processes multiple values of User 'field_test'
        $db_or = db_or(); 
        foreach ($user_field as $item){
            $db_or->condition('field_data_field_test.field_test_value', $item, 'IN'); 
        }
        $query->add_where('test_field_group', $db_or);
    }
    // use dpm() to see added WHERE clause
    //dpm($query);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If User field and Content Type field are allowed to have only single values then you can use UI for filtering view's results.

- add shared field as Contextual Filter
- Provide Default value for the field -> select PHP Code
- enter the following code in the box

`global $user;
$user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
$test_field = $user_fields->field_test['und'][0]['value'];
return $test_field;`

Comment: Say the field doesn't allow multiples?

Comment: it works for single and multiple values. The code simply loads the field values and loops through values array. Then according to each value -  adds appropriate WHERE clause. If there is only one value or the field allows for only one value, then only one WHERE clause will be added to the View query.

Comment: Right. I was still wondering about the UI though. You have a qualifier: "There is no way to accomplish this via UI. At least not if the User field may contain multiple values."

Comment: right, check the updated answer for UI method

Comment: Hmm. Thanks, but if I have to use php code at all I think I should put it in a custom module.

Comment: yes you should. Since you asked about UI method - adding that snippet thru Views UI I think qualifies for it. It is definitely not the best practice and not maintainable, but available as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a way. For the record, here's some starter code.

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_query_alter().
*/
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == VIEWNAME) {
    global $user;
    $user = user_load($user->uid);
    $user_field = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_NAMEOFFIELD');
    if ($user_field) {
      // only care about the first result for now
      $user_field = $user_field[0]['value']; 
    }
    $query->ensure_table("TABLENAME");
    $query->add_where(0, "TABLENAME.NAMEOFFIELD_value", $user_field);
  }
}
```